# How can I set a custom image in UIIMagePickerController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have UIActionSheet with 3 options -

1. Take a photo (from camera)
2. Choose from library
3. Edit photo (if user has profile picture )

I use UIImagePickerController and don't have problems with first 2 options. User choose photo and then can zoom/move to crop one.

**So, my question is - how I can put already saved photo for editing (3rd option) with current scale factor and frame.** 
F.e if I choose "edit photo" I want to get the same photo "state" that I've choosen after preview.

That is how native "contacts" app works!

[image: photo's preview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` object in your delegate method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    if (!image) image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    ....
}
```

Then you can use this image in your own edit view controller. The Contacts app works this way because it writes the edited image back to the `ALAsset`, a destructive change. It is probably a bad idea to do this for users in your app, so it is best to write your own edit image controller that will handle the edited image instead of `UIImagePickerController`. A [search on github](https://github.com/search?q=crop&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Repositories&language=Objective-C) shows tons of open-source repos that can help you with cropping here.

Comment: I supposed it could be some native staff like pickerController.originalImage = originalImage; and pickierController.croppedImage = croppedImage; to run edit mode.